# ROLLUP alternative in Hibernate HQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have this query in which I am using Group By with ROLLUP and it works perfectly in MySQL.

```
SELECT r.Region_Name
 , ad.District_Name
 , COUNT(me.employee_id)
FROM `master_employee` me 
INNER JOIN app_district ad 
     ON me.`district_id` = ad.`DISTRICT_UID`
INNER JOIN region r 
     ON ad.REGION_UID = r.REGION_UID 
GROUP BY ad.REGION_UID, ad.District_Name WITH ROLLUP
```

**HQL**

```
SELECT new com.eld.chart.ChartValues (r.regionName, dm.districtName, STR(COUNT(me.districtModel))) 
FROM MasterEmployeeModel me JOIN me.districtModel dm JOIN dm.regionModel r 
GROUP BY ROLLUP(me.districtModel, r.regionName)
```

shows following exception

```
17:13:51,311 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(masterempl0_.district_id, divisionmo2_.REGION_NAME)' at line 1
```

Is there any valid alternative to ROLLUP for hibernate?